# Selecting a device in ADT kills ADB

Tags: android, eclipse, ubuntu, adb

I am using Eclipse Android Development Tools. For some reason, I am no longer able to connect to a device (I have only tried using AVDs). When I click on a device in DDMS in the Devices pane, ADB shuts down. If I Reset ADB (command line or through Eclipse), the devices will appear again, but clicking on one kills ADB.

I am using Ubuntu 13.04 64 bit.

Comment: Do you have any error logs? Are you trying to connect to a new device or is it a device you could use before?

Comment: The error logs just said there was no device there. These were all virtual devices-I started with the same one I had been using, then started creating new ones. I was a little afraid to connect a real device.

Comment: Ok I see your problem is fixed, I still have a question tough, why are you afraid to connect a real device? It is actually faster than starting a virtual one.

Comment: I was very worried that it would corrupt my phone and I would have to stop debugging eclipse and start debugging my phone.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually got everything back up and running. I zipped the workspace directory, rm -rf'd that, then rm -rf the .eclipse directory in my home directory, and then blew away the whole SDK and reinstalled. There were quite a few errors along the way-files the OS thought were in use that weren't. Something must have gotten badly locked up.